# Using windows drivers in Wine

Tags: drivers, wine, printing

Can Wine be used to overcome printer driver problems? I have tried Mint15 and 16 64 and 32 bit distributions but cannot find a means of running my Canon MG6150.

If wine runs windows software then how do I make it run my printer with windows XP drivers from within Linux using Libre Office.?

Answer (score 1):

Canon has Ubuntu drivers for both the printer and the scanner on their [website](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG6150.aspx).  You need to download the driver, and extract it to install.